# Redis Connection Issue with jedis

Tags: java, redis, jedis

I am using this code but getting connection issue:

```java
JedisConnectionFactory jedisConnectionFactory() {

    JedisConnectionFactory jedisConnectionFactory = null;
    try {
        RedisStandaloneConfiguration redisStandAloneConfiguration = new RedisStandaloneConfiguration(hostName,
            port);
        // make jedis connection factory thread safe (for multi-threaded
        // environment)
        JedisClientConfiguration jedisClientConfiguration = JedisClientConfiguration.builder().usePooling().build();
        jedisConnectionFactory = new JedisConnectionFactory(redisStandAloneConfiguration, jedisClientConfiguration);
        // jedisConnectionFactory uses connection pool by default but with
        // max total of 8
        jedisConnectionFactory.getPoolConfig().setMaxTotal(50);
        jedisConnectionFactory.getPoolConfig().setMaxIdle(50);
        jedisConnectionFactory.afterPropertiesSet();
    } catch (RedisConnectionFailureException e) {
        LOGGER.error("RedisConnectionFailureException in RedisConnector class, Connection break with JEDIS " +
            e.getMessage());
    }

    return jedisConnectionFactory;
}
```

Comment: What is the exception you are getting?

Comment: Jedis coonection issue